# AngularJS ng-if does not work in all modules?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to show/hide my drag and drop when a document comes to the screen. I  used AngularJS and it worked. However, it does not work in all modules. Although I same always the same code but from other modules :

working code :

```
<div ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-allow-dir="true" ng-show="dropIsVisible === true">
    <div class="drop-area-full-page">
        <div class="drop-area-full-page__graphic"></div>
        <div class="drop-area-full-page__info" id="drop-area-full-page__info" ng-bind-html="dropText"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And in AngularJS:

```
$window.addEventListener("dragenter", function (e) {
    if (isFile(e)) {
        lastTarget = e.target;
        $scope.dropIsVisible = true;   
        name = getName($scope, getParent());                     
        $scope.dropText =
            "<b> Dokument ablegen zu </b>" + "<b>" + name+ "</b>";
    }
});

$window.addEventListener("dragleave", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target === document || e.target === lastTarget) {
        $scope.dropIsVisible = false;        

    }
});

$window.addEventListener("dragover", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $scope.dropIsVisible = true;
});
function getParent() {
    return {
        entityName: $stateParams.entity,
        id: $scope.parentId
    };
}

$window.addEventListener("drop", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $scope.dropIsVisible = true;           
    var qs = e.dataTransfer.files[0].name;
    var parent = getParent();
    DokumentUploadMixin.Prepare(qs, e.dataTransfer.files[0], $scope, parent, projection, qs);
    //$window.location.href = routeUtils.getCreateDokumentUrl("Dokument", getParent(), projection, qs);
});
```

};

And the code that is not working:

```
<div ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-allow-dir="true" ng-show="dropIsVisible === true">
    <div class="drop-area-full-page">
        <div class="drop-area-full-page__graphic"></div>
        <div class="drop-area-full-page__info" id="drop-area-full-page__info" ng-bind-html="dropText"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is the same ....
Are there any tips that I should do for making it work in all modules?

Comment: Is the html identical in the two examples? Then your issue seems to be connected to some code which you did not include. As you are speaking about two modules, maybe there is some difference in how the modules are setup? How is your javascript code tied to the app, is the setup run in all moduels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was that i showld apply the scope to event listener cause i added custom event listeners, which are not tracked by Angularjs. In order to make it work applying inside addEventListener callback with $scope.$apply to tell angular update the model.

```
   $window.addEventListener("dragenter", function (e) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            if (isFile(e)) {
                lastTarget = e.target;
                $scope.dropIsVisible = true;   
                name = getName($scope, getParent());                     
                $scope.dropText =
                    "<b> Dokument ablegen zu </b>" + "<b>" + name+ "</b>";
            }
        });
    });

    $window.addEventListener("dragleave", function (e) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (e.target === document || e.target === lastTarget) {
                $scope.dropIsVisible = false;        
            }
        });
    });

    $window.addEventListener("dragover", function (e) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
           e.preventDefault();
           $scope.dropIsVisible = true;
        });
    });
```